# Vue 3 onMounted in prod not updating reactive data (works in dev)

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs

Consider this component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>{{show_data}}</div>
        <div v-for="(item, i) in show_data.list" :key="i">{{item.name}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {onMounted} from "vue"
import {reactive} from "@vue/reactivity"

export default {
    props: {
        definitions: Array
    },
    setup(props) {
        const show_data = reactive({
            list: []
        })

        onMounted(() => {
            props.definitions.forEach(definition => {
                console.log(definition)
                show_data.list.push({name: definition.title, contact: definition.phone_number})
                console.log('show_data so far:')
                console.log(show_data)
            })
        })

        return {
            show_data,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When above code is running in npm run dev, everything executes properly and data populates. But when run in npm run prod data comes in, I can see console.log() showing each definition, and showing full show_data with the actual pushed content, but the actual render does not collect it, the {{show_data.list}} always shows [] and using v-for to iterate through it is also empty. Again, in dev all this works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

A little late an answer, but..

There are two ways of using the composition API (a little confusing). One is class-based:

```
<script lang=js">
export default {
  setup(props) {
    ...
  },
  mounted() {
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

The second one is loose variables with hooks, instantiated by providing `setup` in the script tag:

```
<script lang=js" setup>
  const props = defineProps();
  onMounted(() => {
    ...
  });
</script>
```

So basically you're mixing up the two structures. In your case, replace `onMounted(() => {})` by `mounted() {}` and place it *next to* `setup()`, not in it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you rendered before the onMounted is executed.
Render with v-if condition

```
<template>
<div v-if="show_data.list.lenght > 0">
    <div>{{show_data}}</div>
        <div v-for="(item, i) in show_data.list" :key="i"> 
              {{item.name}}
        </div>
</div>
</template
```

Hope it works for you !

Comment: Same issue either way. Other reactiveness works.